# Save pandas dataframe in PySpark

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pyspark

I have a scenario in PySpark, where I have to do some computations on pandas dataframe in worker level. following is the code snippet

```
def func1(x):
  res_list = []
  for i in x:
    if i
    res_list.append(i)
  pandasdf = pd.DataFrame(res_list,columns=sch)
  <computation>
  <save pandasdf to HDFS>


df = spark.read.csv('/path/')
sch = df.schema.names
rdd = df.rdd.repartition(5)
rdd.foreachPartition(func1)
```

I'm running this in cluster mode. I want to save that Pandas dataframe to HDFS, I tried converting Pandas dataframe to spark dataframe but converting to spark dataframe is not possible in worker node. Can anyone help me how to save that pandas dataframe in side the function to HDFS

Comment: are you saving to s3 ?

Comment: no, saving to hadoop cluster

Comment: What's the error that you're getting?

Comment: Exception: It appears that you are attempting to reference SparkContext from a broadcast variable, action, or transformation. SparkContext can only be used on the driver, not in code that it run on workers. For more information, see SPARK-5063.